# How do I change the entry point in a package.json?

Tags: node.js, package.json

everyone.

I'm new to node.js and front development and I'm working with this template:

https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-bootstrap-admin-template

and I have a silly question that no one seems to address in the forums in a straightforward, simple way.

The template's entry point is the index.html. I tried to change it in the package.json to the login.html, because I want the app to open that page first, of course, but I cannot make it work. I know... It's so silly. I'm sure it's very easy to solve but all the examples I find explain the set up using webpack, and this template doesn't use it.

Could anyone give me a hint? I'll deeply appreciate it.

I copy the package.json for you:

```
{
  "name": "@coreui/coreui-free-bootstrap-admin-template",
  "version": "2.1.15",
  "description": "Free Bootstrap Admin Template",
  "keywords": [
    "admin",
    "admin panel",
    "admin template",
    "bootstrap",
    "css",
    "dashboard",
    "framework",
    "front-end",
    "responsive",
    "sass",
    "ui kit",
    "webapp"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://coreui.io",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-bootstrap-admin-template/issues",
    "email": "support@coreui.io"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": {
    "name": "Łukasz Holeczek",
    "url": "http://holeczek.pl",
    "github": "https://github.com/mrholek",
    "twitter": "https://twitter.com/lukaszholeczek"
  },
  "contributors": [
    {
      "name": "Andrzej Kopański",
      "url": "https://github.com/xidedix"
    }
  ],
  "main": "src/index.html",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-bootstrap-admin-template.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm-run-all build-clean build-copy build-vendors",
    "build-clean": "rimraf dist",
    "build-copy": "copyfiles -a -e \"src/scss/**/*\" -u 1 \"src/**/*\" dist/",
    "build-vendors": "node build/vendors.js",
    "css": "npm-run-all --parallel css-compile* --sequential css-prefix css-minify*",
    "css-compile": "node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 src/scss/style.scss src/css/style.css",
    "css-compile-vendors": "node build/vendors-sass.js",
    "css-lint": "stylelint --config build/.stylelintrc --syntax scss \"src/scss/**/*.scss\"",
    "css-minify": "cleancss --level 1 --source-map --source-map-inline-sources --output src/css/style.min.css src/css/style.css",
    "css-prefix": "postcss --config build/postcss.config.js --replace \"src/css/*.css\" \"!src/css/*.min.css\"",
    "js": "npm-run-all --parallel js-compile* js-lint*",
    "js-compile": "cross-env PLUGINS=true babel src/js/src/ --out-dir src/js/ --source-maps",
    "js-lint": "eslint src/js/src",
    "localhost": "browser-sync start --server \"./src\" --serveStatic \"./\" --files \"!./src/js/src/**/*, ./src/**/*, !./src/scss/**/*\"",
    "localhost-dist": "browser-sync start --server \"./dist\"",
    "pug": "node build/pug.js",
    "release-version": "node build/change-version.js",
    "serve": "npm-run-all --parallel localhost watch-css watch-js",
    "watch-css": "nodemon --ignore dist/ -e scss -x \"npm run css\"",
    "watch-js": "nodemon --watch src/js/src/ -x \"npm run js\"",
    "watch-pug": "nodemon -e pug -x \"npm run pug\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.12",
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
    "@coreui/icons": "0.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "^3.1.4",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "~4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "pace-progress": "1.0.2",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
    "simple-line-icons": "2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-strip": "^0.1.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "chalk": "^2.4.2",
    "clean-css-cli": "^4.3.0",
    "copyfiles": "^2.1.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-compat": "^3.2.0",
    "foreach-cli": "^1.8.1",
    "js-beautify": "^1.10.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss-cli": "^6.1.3",
    "pug": "^2.0.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.3",
    "stylelint": "^10.1.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "^3.3.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.3.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^3.0.1",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 1 major version",
    ">= 1%",
    "Chrome >= 45",
    "Firefox >= 38",
    "Edge >= 12",
    "Explorer >= 10",
    "iOS >= 9",
    "Safari >= 9",
    "Android >= 4.4",
    "Opera >= 30"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The index.html is the entry point because that's how web servers work. Changing the package.json won't change which file is served as the index. You could modify the index.html to redirect to the login.html. It's not really clear why you want the login.html to be the entry point though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to implement a backend in Java with security for this project and use this template as front, so the entry point should be a login to authenticate before accessing any other resource.

Comment: What if the user happens to be logged in already? It sounds like you need some custom logic on the backend to redirect to the login page when the user is not logged in, otherwise respond with the index page.

Comment: Yes. That logic will be covered as you said by the backend in Java with Spring Security as a separate project, but I haven't got to that point, yet. I thought I could just change the entry point only in the front project without interacting with the backend, just to see how the landing page of the app would look like, but I understand what you mean. I need to read some more, apparently. It's my first web app with a frontend as a separate project. Thank you for your help.